# Insertion-sort error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, insertion-sort

I am trying to make an insertion sorting program that sorted a list in ascending order. I'm getting the error:

```
line 16, in <module> if listNums[x] < listNums[i]:
```

For this program:

```
    listNums = [54, 21, 76, 43, 65, 98, 65, 32, 34, 38]

    x = 1
    i = 0
    Copy = 0

    for z in range (0, len(listNums)):
           if listNums[x] < listNums[i]:
                  Copy = listNums[i]
                  listNums[i] = listNums[x]
                  listNums[x] = Copy
           i = i + 1
           x = x + 1

    print(listNums)
```

Comment: What is the actual text of the rror you are getting?

Comment: the `bisect` module will do all the work for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are it's a bounds error because `x` eventually increments up to `len(listNums)` which is 1 beyond the bounds of the zero-indexed array.

Try only iterating through `range(0, len(listNums)-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to point out that there is a better way to do it, namely

```
listNums = [54, 21, 76, 43, 65, 98, 65, 32, 34, 38]

listNums.sort()
print listNums
```

which gives

```
[21, 32, 34, 38, 43, 54, 65, 65, 76, 98]
=> None
```

(compiled on repl.it)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an `insertion sort error` 
In the last iteration i.e. len(listNums)th iteration, the value of x goes beyond the length of list that's why it gives `IndexError: list index out of range`